# org-babel-insert-result: Wrong type argument: markerp, nil

Tags: org-babel

I use org-mode to structure my emacs configuration files. Recently, I have the following problem: some of my emacs-lisp blocks generate the following error at runtime:

org-babel-insert-result: Wrong type argument: markerp, nil

This is the case for this block for example:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
   (prefer-coding-system 'utf-8)
   (setq default-file-name-coding-system 'utf-8)
   (set-default-coding-systems 'utf-8)
   (set-terminal-coding-system 'utf-8)
   (set-keyboard-coding-system 'utf-8)
   ;; backwards compatibility as default-buffer-file-coding-system
   ;; is deprecated in 23.2.
   (if (boundp buffer-file-coding-system)
     (setq buffer-file-coding-system 'utf-8)
     (setq default-buffer-file-coding-system 'utf-8))
;; Treat clipboard input as UTF-8 string first; compound text next, etc.
   (setq x-select-request-type '(UTF8_STRING COMPOUND_TEXT TEXT STRING))
#+END_SRC
```

where the error seems to come from the following line:

```
   (setq x-select-request-type '(UTF8_STRING COMPOUND_TEXT TEXT STRING))
```

But his is also the case for the following block :

```
(setq org-todo-keywords
      '((sequence "TODO" "FEEDBACK" "VERIFY" "|" "DONE" "DELEGATED" "CANCELED" "INACTIVE")))
(setq org-todo-keyword-faces
      '(
("TODO" . (:foreground "red" :background "misty rose" :weight bold)) 
("FEEDBACK"  .  (:foreground "dark orange" :background "misty rose" :weight bold))
("VERIFY" .  (:foreground "dark orange" :background "misty rose" :weight bold))
("INACTIVE" .  (:foreground "dim gray" :background "white smoke" :weight bold))
("DONE" .  (:foreground "dark green" :background "pale green" :weight bold))
("DELEGATED" . (:foreground "dark blue" :background "light steel blue" :weight bold))
("CANCELED" . (:foreground "dim gray" :background "light steel blue" :weight bold))
))
```

... As well as many others...
It seems to be related to the `setq' function but I can't say for sure. Small precision, these errors are not apparent during the execution of the elisp file generated during the launching of emacs, thus without visible direct incidence from the point of view of the configuration. However, I would like to understand where the problem comes from.

Comment: You mean you try to evaluate the code block with `C-c C-c` and you get that error? If so, can you `M-x toggle-debug-on-error`, try again and post the backtrace?

Comment: ```Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Invalid face" org-block-background)
  internal-set-lisp-face-attribute(org-block-background :inherit fixed-pitch 0)
  set-face-attribute(org-block-background nil :inherit fixed-pitch)
  set-buffer-variable-pitch()
  run-hooks(change-major-mode-after-body-hook text-mode-hook outline-mode-hook org-mode-hook)
  apply(run-hooks (change-major-mode-after-body-hook text-mode-hook outline-mode-hook org-mode-hook))
(...)``` is the begining of the backtrace for `(setq x-select-request-type '(UTF8_STRING COMPOUND_TEXT STRING TEXT))'

Comment: ```Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Invalid face" org-block-background)
  internal-set-lisp-face-attribute(org-block-background :inherit fixed-pitch 0)
  set-face-attribute(org-block-background nil :inherit fixed-pitch)
  set-buffer-variable-pitch()
  run-hooks(change-major-mode-after-body-hook text-mode-hook outline-mode-hook org-mode-hook)
  apply(run-hooks (change-major-mode-after-body-hook text-mode-hook outline-mode-hook org-mode-hook))
``` is the one for TODO keywords config. It seems that the problem is related to face config.

Comment: What does `M-x describe-face RET org-block-background` say?  If it is not defined, then you either have to define it (with `defface`) or you have to find the place where it is used and change it to a face that exists.